# Using AIC to select an upper bin for a counting variable

Tags: modeling, epidemiology, predictor, inference

I have some patient data and I'm using a logistic model to explore factors that might affect a patient considered severe/not severe for a disease (the DV).

Many of the variables are counts; counts of prescriptions in one year, counts of diagnoses codes, GP visits, etc.  To take one example, GP visits.  Commonly, this is modeled as 0, 1 or 2+ visits a year (so, two dummy variables, each compared with 0 visits).  It is never modeled as a continuous variable as risk to outcome is not thought linear, the top of the distribution is often erratic - and physicians hate continuous variables ... !

Using 0/1/2+ feels too simplistic however and I was considering a different method for determining the 'upper bin'.  An approach I'm trying is modeling the IV alone against the DV using many bins (e.g. 0/1+, 0/1/2+, 0/1/2/3+) and saving the AICc score for each one.  I then plot the score for each model and select the one with the lowest score (with an eye on it being sensible too).

Is this a valid approach?  Or might there be another way for an inferential model?

Thanks, Richard